# Connecting query code with many different divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If I have 5 divs

```
<div id="" class=""> Div11 </div>
<div id="" class=""> Div12 </div>
<div id="" class=""> Div13 </div>
<div id="" class=""> Div14 </div>
<div id="" class=""> Div15 </div>
```

And jquery code for like:

On click some div to hide it.

Now when I say in jquery `$("DIV").click(function(){ $("DIV").hide(); });`

I named it DIV so I can ask you these questions:

1. Is ID or CLASS one that is going to be same as all others and the other one different.
2. If ID is different and if i have first div `id="div1"` and second `id="div2"` and till last, how can I connect query to every single one of them?

I tried but it is working only on one div... Like even better question:

If I set some textarea as hide in jquery on page load. And on div click it need to show up... My script works only on 1 div on others not, and the textarea is not hidden as it should be.

UPDATE:

My real thing is that I have php file and mysql database

mysql database contains first name and id and last name
it have 10 names

in my php file I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fname = $row['firstname'];
    $id = $row['id'];
            echo $fname."

            <textarea id='div".$id."' class='divsss'>Enter last name:</textarea>

";

    }

}
```

Then I have jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {


                $('.divsss').keypress(function(event) {

                var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if (key == 13) {

                    var lname = $('.divsss').val();

                    var forid = '<?php echo $id; ?>';

                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "intodb.php",
                        data: {ln: lname, fi: forid},
                        success: function(status) {
                        alert("lname: " + lname + "for id: " + forid);
                            $('.divsss').val('');

                        }

                    });
                    };
                }); 

        });
    </script>
```

It wont work but when I change it to ids with same id it worrk only for first output it have value as 0 or 1. But When I try by classes it is not working.
And inside intodb.php I just have update into DB...

Comment: A class value can be shared between many elements. An id value cannot. If you want to be able to address a lot of elements for the same purpose, give them all a common class and use `$(".common-class")`.

Comment: I updated question can you help me now? I need to find ID from textarea where the ENTER was entered... And separate it as like if id is: id="div55"
I need to separate div and 55...
@Pointy

Comment: jQuery calls your event handler such that `this` refers to the `<textarea>` element where the keypress happened. You don't have to "find" it.

Comment: I got you.  So basically I would say **this** and then add var id = $(this).attr('id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding Your Questions**

> Is ID or CLASS one that is going to be same as all others and the
>   other one different.

The [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute by definition should be unique and can be used to identify a specific element within the DOM. The [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute on the other hand can be shared my multiple elements and is generally used for styling the elements.

> If ID is different and if i have first div id="div1" and second
>   id="div2" and till last, how can I connect query to every single one
>   of them?

You can accomplish this in a variety of ways. jQuery supports a wide variety of attribute-based selectors, so you could easily target every element that has an `id` that "starts-with div" as seen below :

```
// This would hide any elements that have an ID that starts with "div"
$('[id^="div"]').hide();
```

Likewise, you could also apply a CSS class to all of those elements to group them and select them that way :

```
<div class='your-class'></div>
<div class='your-class'></div>
<div class='your-class'></div>
```

along with :

```
// This would hide any elements that have the class "your-class"
$('.your-class').hide();
```

**Regarding Your Code**

With regards to your actual code, you'll need to ensure that you are properly scoping what you are trying to do within your `keypress` events :

```
// When a key is pressed within this element (presumably a <textarea> or <input>
$('.divsss').keypress(function(event) {
        // Store a reference to this for your AJAX callback
        var _self = $(this);
        // Get the key
        var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which); 
        // If it was enter
        if (key == 13) {
            // Get the last name (of this element), using $(this)
            var lname = $(this).val();
            // Get an id predefined by your server-side PHP
            var forid = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
            // Make your AJAX post
            $.post('intodb.php',{ln: lname, fi: forid}, function(status){
                    alert("lname: " + lname + "for id: " + forid);
                    _self.val('');
            });
});
```

Comment: Don't know why but now my ENTER key doesn not work it work as new line

Answer (score 0):

```
$("DIV").on("click", function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

use ***this*** and you will hide the div that is the caller of the function.

Comment: Okay and if I have php echo output from database. And my id for div is div+<?php echo $id; ?>. and I have like 10 outputs and ids are div1,div2,...,div10 .  and on click on div 3 with id div3 .. How can I tell jquery I am clicking on id div3 should I say on click $("#div<?php echo $id; ?>")? Or something else? Because I got error by doing this it use $id only first one from database?

Comment: No, it is as simple as this. If you have any number of divs there is no need to address the specific div. In jQuery you have a lot of different ways to address elements. They are called selectors. If you want to address all div tags you simply have to do it like this $('div') if you want to address div that are created on runtime you should do it like hits. $(document).on("click", "div", function(){}) if you like to hide the div that is clicked you should do it like this  $(document).on("click", "div", function(){$(this).hide()}) . Using "this" refers to this specific div

Comment: Please take in mind that the correct way to address anything that is created runtime is $(document).on("click", "ELEMENT", function(){}) because in any other way events wont be attached to elements that are created runtime.

Comment: I updated question with my problem  take a look please

Comment: SO can I say :
$(document).on("click", "#div<?php echo $id; ?>", function(){$(this).hide()})

Comment: Damn I think i know what is wrong, I dont need to put echo $id there.... I need to on clicked div to separate name from echoed id inside fetch from database.... So do I need to say on click this and then somehow say id from this div i clicked and then separate div and $id and then send with ajax?

Comment: You dont have to set the id at all when you use $(document).on("click", "div", function(){$(this).hide()}) it will hide only the div that is clicked and no one else. div is selector by it self no need for specific id.

Comment: I understand that but I am not trying to hide div it was example I told u I updated question I am trrying to get id from that div that is keypressed on... Because that id contains id from my database and that id is id where is that name....

Comment: Sorry I did miss that. So  there is keypressed selector in jquery. it works for input not all browser supports for div. If there is and input you can get the div is by using something like this. $(document).on("keypress", "input", function(){ alert($(this).parent().attr('id')});

Answer (score 0):

When you set an `ID` (Identification), as it names indicate, it is **ONLY** for one div.

If you want to use a css property in more than one div, then you have to use a class and in your case you can hide them using the following code:

```
$(".hideDiv").click(function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

supposing that you are using `.hideDiv` class in all of your divs, like this:

```
<div id="div01" class="hideDiv"> Div11 </div>
<div id="div02" class="hideDiv"> Div12 </div>
...
```

and so on.

Answer (score -1):

use class and the `$('.class')` as your jQuery identifier ..

In jQuery, `$('.class')` is meant to identify classes and `$('#ID')` identifies the element with a specific ID.  Both have their uses .. But in this case .. `class` is what you want.

```
<div id="div1" class="div"> Div11 </div>
<div id="div2" class="div"> Div12 </div>
<div id="div3" class="div"> Div13 </div>
<div id="div4" class="div"> Div14 </div>
<div id="div5" class="div"> Div15 </div>


$(".div").click(function(){ $(".div").hide(); });
```

Conversely  --  `ID`'s are ALWAYS unique identifiers ...  Keep them unique.  `Class`es are meant to "classify" groups of objects...

Comment: I see that, but I have little same but different problem I will update question :P

Comment: You can use `$(this).hide();` instead of making reference again to the same class.

Comment: He isn't wanting to hide ($this) he's wanting to hide all 5 divs .. at least as far as I understand ...  And identifying with the class will allow a better understanding of identification, which he's clearly in need of ..

Comment: _On click some div to hide it._ I think he only wants one div each time.

Comment: --  I read into this: "how can I connect query to every single one of them"

Comment: @Zak I did not downvote you, if it is what you mean. I just told what I though.