# Retrieve textarea's id on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

On `keypress` in a `textarea`, I need to select the `id` and separate it. How is this possible?

If I have some jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("keypress", "textarea", function(){$(this).
```

How can I get the `textarea`'s `id` and separate it like if the `id` is `id="ta1"`

Comment: where is on keypress?

Comment: my bad i wrote click

Comment: Above question helped me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are just interested in the numeric value part of the ID, you could easily strip off all non-numeric characters using a Regular Expression using the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function :

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(){
     // Get your ID
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     // Strip off any non-numeric values
     var idNumber = id.replace(/\D+/g, ''); 
});
```

**Working Example**

```js
$('textarea').keypress(function() {
  // Get your ID
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  // Strip off any non-numeric values
  var idNumber = id.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  alert('<textarea> #' + idNumber + ' was typed in');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre>Text Area 1</pre>
<textarea id='ta1'></textarea>
<hr />
<pre>Text Area 2</pre>
<textarea id='ta2'></textarea>
<hr />
<pre>Text Area 3</pre>
<textarea id='ta3'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks and can you tell me maybe where I can find more about this:
( /^\D+/g, '') I am wordless

Comment: Sure. That's just a Regular Expression, this states that you any characters that match the expression `\D`, which represents all non-digit characters, should be replaced by an empty string `''`.

Comment: Thanks man this helped me a lot... It is for entering more info about some person in database. And now when I fetch data I have fname and id. I echo fname and textarea where I put id to div$id and because of that $id I need to separate because with ajax then I can send lastname which was entered in textarea and id for what first name I am adding info. I asked one question about that before this one but I didnt get anything and I think this is answer but if I am mistaking something let me know: Here is my last question: Thanks mate !
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/61175798?noredirect=1

Comment: I tried to address a few of your issues within that thread. See my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36801059/557445).

Comment: I saw it now thanks I had problem with this like 20 days :D I asked like 30 questions bout this :D !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('body').on('keypress','textarea',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id')
var ta = id.substring(0,2);
var num = id.substring(2);
});
```